# Java JMapViewer: How can I change the color of a MapPolygon?

Tags: java, colors, stroke, jmapviewer

I'm creating an application for drawing pollution information on a JMapViewer. I want to do this with MapPolygons, but I didn't find a good documentation about it. I succeeded to create new MapPolygons like this:

```
private MapPolygon getPolygon(double lat, double lon, Color col){
    List<Coordinate> coords = new ArrayList<>();

    //add all points to the list...

    MapPolygon poly = new MapPolygonImpl(coords); 
    return poly;
}
```

I'm wondering how I could change the color and remove the border of the MapPolygon. There is no function setColor or such...

I tried directly with the constructor, but this doesn't work:

```
MapPolygon poly = new MapPolygonImpl(coords, Color.RED, new BasicStroke(0));
```

Does anybody know how I can change the color of the MapPolygon?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Because `MapPolygonImpl` extends `MapObjectImpl`, `MapPolygonImpl` inherits `setColor()` and `setBackColor()` from `MapObjectImpl`. `MapPolygonImpl` uses these colors in its implementation of `paint()`. The colors are stored in the parent class's `Style` attribute, initialized by calling `getDefaultStyle()` during construction.

You can vary the *alpha* component of the chosen `Color` to achieve a variety of effects; the example below uses a 12.5% light gray.

```
MapPolygonImpl poly = new MapPolygonImpl(coords);
Color color = new Color(0x20202020, true);
poly.setColor(color);
poly.setBackColor(color);
poly.setStroke(new BasicStroke(0));
map.addMapPolygon(poly);
```

[image]

If the existing color is satisfactory, a similar effect may be achieved by setting the color to the background color.

```
MapPolygonImpl poly = new MapPolygonImpl(route);
poly.setColor(poly.getBackColor());
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it out. You have to create a layer and a style:

```
    Layer global = new Layer("Global");
    Style style = new Style();
    style.setBackColor(col);
    style.setColor(col);
    style.setStroke(new BasicStroke(0));
    MapPolygon poly = new MapPolygonImpl(global,"",coords,style);
    return poly;
```

Comment: You can change the color or style, whether a layer is used or not.