# coordinates point is in jmapviewer polygon?

Tags: java, polygon, jmapviewer

I'm making a program in Java that displays a map using JMapViewer and draws a static polygon. When the user clicks in the map the program say "the point where you have clicked is in polygon" or "not in polygon". How I can do for calculate when the point is in polygon or not? Is there any ready method/class to do that?

Thank you,
Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In outline,

- Construct a `MapPolygon` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30830391/230513).
- Detect mouse clicks using a custom `DefaultMapController` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24688091/230513).
- In `mouseClicked()`, construct a `java.awt.Polygon` by iterating through the `List<ICoordinate>` returned by `MapPolygon::getPoints`; use the `JMapViewer::getPosition` method to convert each `ICoordinate` to a `Point`.
- Use [`Polygon::contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html#contains-int-int-) to determine whether the mouse coordinates are inside this `Polygon`.

[image]